# Jquery mobile Page

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile for my mobile app. I want to make a page where `data-role=content`  should be scroll when it is overflow but  it is scrolling whole page with header and footer. I want to scroll only content div and header  and footer divs should be fixed. I have already seen iscrollview but its only working in iPhone or any other way.

Please suggest how can I make this design.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a data-position="fixed" to your header and footer. Check this example below:

```
<div data-role="page"> 
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">...</div> 
    <div data-role="content">...</div> 
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">...</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: I have used this structure  but content div is not scrolling

Comment: Hi, Please look at my updated structure. Also do you have enough content for the page to scroll? Do you have a link ?

Comment: i dont have link but  check this link http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4; the plugin is available on this link. I want to create the same wich is available in this plugin but i dont want to use this plugin becoz its not working in all plat forms.

Comment: Check this page and scroll http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html

You'll notice that the header and footer will not scroll. That's what you want right?

Comment: yes, but can we change the style of scroll bar so that it seems to apper in content div  and make header and footer so that they are not hide after clicking on the page

Comment: Apply data-tap-toggle="false" to header and footer. 
For a nice scrollbar, you can use this jquery mobile plugin:
http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4; it may not be jQuery, but it is a great JavaScript plugin for Mobile Scrolling.

You would add an ID to each UL and attach a scroll to each one separately.